# Health Benefit of Social Nudity - Improvement of Homeostasis?

Tags: body-temperature, reference-request, social-anthropology, nudity-nude-naked

I have been conducting extensive research over the last few years on the history of nudity in social situations, and I am looking to expand my research base now I have come across a few other interesting facts.

I have also given @CareyGregory’s rhetorical question some thought.

> What does the body need to do to remain at its normal temperature?

Additionally to another question I asked on parasite reduction through being naked, I am asking...

> Will going nude improve homeostasis?

### Example

Professor Peter Wheeler of Liverpool John Moore’s University says that the average human can lose heat at a rate in excess of 1 kilowatt, which is the amount of heat put out by a 1 bar electric fire.  If you have body hair, you can still lose heat by sweating, but the rate of heat loss will be reduced because the air flow across the body would be severely reduced which in turn would reduce the rate at which the sweat is going to evaporate.  Sweating into a fur coat would have been no use to our ancestors. ([Wheeler, 1994](https://doi.org/10.1016/0047-2484(91)90002-D)) ([Horizon: What's The Problem With Nudity, 2008](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00j0hnm))

Does wearing clothing hamper the body’s ability to lose excess heat more than body hair?  What studies have been done to corroborate this?

### References

Horizon: What's The Problem With Nudity (2008). [TV] Directed by Paul King. UK:BBC.
BBC iPlayer: http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00j0hnm

Wheeler, P. E. (1994). *The thermoregulatory advantages of hominid bipedalism in open equatorial environments: the contribution of increased convective heat loss and cutaneous evaporative cooling*. Journal of Human Evolution 21(2): pp. 107-115.
DOI: [10.1016/0047-2484(91)90002-D](https://doi.org/10.1016/0047-2484(91)90002-D)

Does this indicate one physical benefit to nudity (quicker heat loss for body temperature regulation).

Comment: Obviously that's only a benefit in a hot climate. It's quite the opposite in a cold climate.

Comment: What does the body need to do to remain at its normal temperature? If it needs to radiate heat, that's a hot climate. If it needs to retain heat, that's a cold climate. Being naked inside a heated building in a cold climate isn't a benefit since the building's temperature would have to be raised to remain comfortable. If being naked in a cold climate has benefits, those benefits have nothing to do with temperature regulation.

Comment: 1kw is so huge! unbelievable! if we could get rid of our heat as light it would really be so useful:))