# Is it bad for skin to be naked so often?

Tags: dermatology, sweat, oil-of-skin, dry-skin

I often feel itchy, very quickly after I take off my shirt. So it made me think about it.

I can Imagine that cloth absorbs our sweat and thus prevents it from accumulating on skin which I don't think is a good thing also I think wearing clothes makes our skin dry out less so That must be good too. But I'm not sure. specially because our ancestors used to be naked often so I guess our bodies are probably more fit to be naked.

My question is the harms and benefits of having our skin exposed to air directly when we are in the house. So I'm not about benefits of getting more direct sun, although there is some indirect light in the house of course. But I'm interested on the effect of having our skin exposed to direct air most of the time and not having cloth being rubbed against it all the time.

If anyone knows about why I get itchy after taking off my shirt I would appreciate that too of course but that is not the main focus of this question.

Comment: Asking why you get itchy is clearly off topic, so what is the main focus of your question?

Comment: @Carey I've tried to make it clear that my question is not about why "I get itchy" my question is about the possible harms of having ones skin exposed to the air specially in rather dry areas with humidity around 10-20%. I mentioned that I get itchy because that Is what triggered me to ask this question and I said that if someone would be also so kind to comment for me why one might get almost immediately itchy after taking of their shirt they would make me happy. But that is not the focus of the question. I don't want to judge but did you really read my post fully when you made this comment?

Comment: I can see where you are coming from @CareyGregory, but although there is mention of “I” in the question I don’t feel this time that the question is asking for personal advice.  It is just giving anecdotal evidence of what the question is asking

Comment: Related - https://health.stackexchange.com/q/12741 and https://health.stackexchange.com/q/12740

Comment: @ChrisRogers thank you so much! btw what does I can see where you are coming from mean exactly? Is it like I get your point? how does it mean like that if so?

Comment: @yukashimahuksay - that is correct.  It is another way of saying "I understand why you are saying that"

Comment: Yes, I read your question. Did you read my comment? Why even mention the itchiness if that's not what you're asking about?

Comment: Because I think that is a very relevant observation that I have and maybe someone who reads it might realize that it also holds true for them. And thinking about it can lead them to finding a better answer for the question. It was not so important tho, that's why I only devoted one line to it. However I also said at the end that: "If anyone knows about why I get itchy after taking off my shirt I would appreciate that too of course but that is not the main focus of this question." And it's like asking people for an extra favor if they want to make me happy.

Comment: @Carey I do that often in stackoverflow for example that I say at the end of my question that I would appreciate any extra comments on my code to make it better, but that it is not the focus of the question. But if you really think it's necessarily to remove it, I would. I'm quite sure you have much more experience than me in this community and I trust your judgment and I don't want to break the community standards. btw, I'm truly sorry that I asked you weather or not you had read my whole question.

Comment: Just a thought and only speculation but maybe the itchy feeling is the lack of experience of breeze across your naked skin?  Is it hairy areas you feel itchy?  Is it only slight itchiness or heavy?  Nobody can really answer that properly through the internet and although it is just a side question regarding an anecdotal side issue unrelated to the question, it is extremely close to asking for personal advice.  Be careful with that with any future questions

Comment: @ChrisRogers it's not really like a question that I need an answer for. It's not an issue that I have that I want to fix or anything. it's just something that I wanted to know just out of scientific curiosity. And not I feel that mostly on my back. it's like I'm sitting on my chair. everything is normal. I take of my shirt. and I feel itchy in a few minutes. If I don't pay attention to it it usually just goes away after like 20-30 minutes.